UE5.3 : Unable to build on Android, licensing service and/or array size too large
I’ve been scratching my head over a problem for several weeks now.
Initially, I released a “test” version of my game, which worked fine on Android but had very little content. Now I’ve finished a viable version of my game, but when I try to build, I get a whole bunch of different errors. The first error was that the package exceeded 2GB, to which I responded by checking the box allowing me to exceed this limit.
Since then, I’ve been getting this error :
enter image description here
I tried tons of tutorials that made me install and reinstall Android Studio, the SDK, and NDK, but nothing seemed to work. I keep running into errors, either because the SDKs are incorrect (although the tutorials have me install things not mentioned in the UE5 documentation...) or I end up back at the initial problem.
What I still don't understand is how I was able to release an Android version that worked, but adding content seems to have broken it. And when I try to remove that content to test, it still doesn't work...
Any help would by wonderful, thanks !
P.S.: I don't know anything about coding, and I use Unreal because blueprints spare me from having to do it.
Edit : So meanwhile, I've tried another 10,000 things and I can't seem to get precisely the error I screenshotted (and yet I haven't touched anything related to licensing stuff). Now I'm getting this error:
 UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Making .apk with Gradle...
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * What went wrong:
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):    > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5-1.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):      Searched in the following locations:
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5-1/gradle-7.5-1.pom
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5-1/gradle-7.5-1.pom
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):      Required by:
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):          project :
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Try:
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED in 5s
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Users\ORDENADOR\Documents\Unreal Projects\LustnFarm\Intermediate\Android\arm64\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleDebug
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): (see C:\Users\ORDENADOR\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_5.3\Log.txt for full exception trace)
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool executed for 0h 2m 8s
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
    UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): BUILD FAILED
    PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error


In all cases, error output should be pasted rather than embedded in a screen-dump. This example is not only impossible to find by searching, but it's also too tiny to read. The question should show a block delimited by triple-back-ticks of the output, from the first red line (most important) no further than the line after the last red line. Could you also look up what in what jar file that licensing library should be contained and whether it's in your CLASSPATH?

Sorry, first post, I don't have the right reflexes yet. I've updated my post.
